# Python: Sorting Nested list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Suppose there is a list like [name,score]

```
record = [['Harry',37.21],['Berry',37.21],['Tina',37.2],['Akriti',41],['Harsh',39]]
```

I want to print the name of record which has second lowest score. If two records have same lowest score I need to sort them based on their names and then print. 
I know we can use

`record.sort(key..)`

to get values sorted according to score. But how to check for second lowest score and then check for name.

Comment: the second lowest would be `record[1]` if the list is sorted from low to high based on its score

Comment: But will I sort the second lowest record again based on name ?

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking...

Comment: @b4hand thats not really a duplicate ... close but there is no secondary sort in the case of ties

Answer (score 6):

```
second_lowest = sorted(my_list,key=lambda x:x[::-1])[1]
```

not sure what you mean about ties and whatnot ... but this should sort first by score and sort ties by alphabetical name, by reversing the items we are sorting records of `[score,name]`

this basically just abuses the fact that tuples/lists naturally sort on progressive keys when the first key ties

```
sorted([[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[3,2,1],[1,1,2]])
```

Comment: I disagree that that's an abuse :-)

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wanted. he wanted a sorting by grade, reversed, and then by alphabetical order: "If two records have same lowest score I need to sort them based on their names and then print"

Comment: this will sort alphabetically on the name in the case of any tie .... regardless of where the tie occures ...  Im not sure how that doesnt answer the question

Comment: ok fixed... the problem was that reversed returns a generator instead of a list

Comment: yeah but reversed gives back an iterator ... I think x[::-1] is as pythonic as i can get it :P

Comment: it sorts on em wrong it uses their id or something `reversed([1,2,3]) < reversed([3,2,1])` will return true sometimes and false sometimes to demonstrate

Comment: so I would have to do something like `lambda x:list(reversed(x))` which isnt really any better than x[::-1]

Comment: Yes, this one is much better. I will vote it up in this situation, but what if we want different order on name and score?

Comment: Oh I see... yes in that case `cmp` may be better (or a key that is overly confusing) ... (I hadnt really considered that case :)

Answer (score 4):

Like others have said, you can easily get a list sorted on value and name by reversing the sublists.

```
>>> sorted_data = sorted(record, key=lambda x: x[::-1])
>>> sorted_data
[['Tina', 37.2], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39], ['Akriti', 41]]
```

But it seems that you want *all second lowest values*. Obviously you cannot just index `sorted_data[1]` then. I would suggest an approach like this,

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(sublist) for _, sublist in groupby(sorted_data, lambda x: x[1])][1]
[['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21]]
```

This groups your sorted data on the value to easily allow you to access all `[name, value]` pairs having the same second smallest value.

Comment: I read the question again and it seems that this is indeed what he was trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

```
second = sorted(record, key=lambda(a,b):(b,a))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a more flexible way, like using different order for name and score, you can use cmp.
Try this:

```
cfunc = lambda x,y: cmp(x[0],y[0]) if x[1] == y[1] else cmp(x[1],y[1])
record.sort(cmp=cfunc)
record[1]
```

Or:

```
cfunc = lambda x,y: -cmp(x[0],y[0]) if x[1] == y[1] else cmp(x[1],y[1])
```

Depends on whether you want to sort the name ascending or descending.

The general idea here is you have to define the order explicitly.
In this case it's defined by the cfunc. 
See the document for detail: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp

Comment: while this does work to a novice python programmer this is not very clear in what its doing ...additionally I believe python recommends using key= instead of cmp in sorts (as it is faster)  (that said the -1 isnt  from me and I will offset it with a +1 since this is technically a correct answer)

Comment: I agree this is probably not very pythonic but it's kind of more general than your answer and I would definitely want to see a more pythonic solution than both our answer. Thanks for the offset as well.

Comment: you should point out the case where this might method may be more appropriate (just copy your comment on my answer to this answer)

Comment: Why not `lambda x,y: cmp(x[1],y[1]) or cmp(x[0],y[0])`?